# Mount second harddrive at startup through GUI

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive, steam

I'm new to Linux but I want to use it as my mean operating system.
One of the criteria of that is to play steam games on it.

Therefore I need to download the games on a second HDD,
since my SSD is to small and its already dual booting: windows, Ubuntu.

I did got all that running, But every time I reboot the second HDD is marked as read only.

I really wish there a way in the GUI to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I reject my question....

like all the 'how to's' on the interwebs this works through *gnome disk utility* just **fine** in my virtual machine. But not on my **physical** computer. I will format my drive now and start from scratch.